# Generic repository in ASP.NET Core without having a separate AddScoped line per table in Startup.cs?

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a generic repository in my project.
Consider the following controller snippet

```cs
public class Lookup1Controller : Controller
{
    readonly MyDbContext _db;

    public Lookup1Controller(MyDbContext dataContext)
    {
        _db = dataContext;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        IGenericRepository<Lookup1> _repository = new GenericRepository<Lookup1>(_db);
        var lookup1s = await _repository.SelectAll();

        return  View(lookup1s);
    }
```

I don't see the need to have my Database reference both in my Generic repository as well as each of my controllers.

I refactor it to:

```cs
public class Lookup1Controller : Controller
{
    private IGenericRepository<Lookup1> _repository;

    public Lookup1Controller(IGenericRepository<Lookup1> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var lookup1s = await _repository.SelectAll();

        return  View(lookup1s);
    }

}
```

which is much neater and ASP.NET 5 best practice from what I read.
but I will get the following error if I access that controller route in my browser:

```cs
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyProject.Data.IGenericRepository`1[MyProject.Models.Lookup1]' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Controllers.Lookup1.
```

because of I haven't injected the GenericRepository to use the interface.

I add to my `Startup.cs` an `AddScoped` line for each and every of my tables in the `ConfigureServices` method

```cs
services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Lookup1>,GenericRepository<Lookup1>> ();
services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Lookup2>,GenericRepository<Lookup2>> ();
services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Lookup3>,GenericRepository<Lookup3>> ();
services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Lookup4>,GenericRepository<Lookup4>> ();
etc
```

so that my code runs without throwing an exception.

However my database has about 100 simple lookup tables. When I look at the above 100 lines of code it just doesn't look right.

It feels like copy and paste code. Each time I add a new table by adding a new model and controller with view my code will compile without giving me an error. But if I run the program and go to that view I could get the controller run error if I forgot to add the  AddScoped line to my `Startup.cs`. Not really good for maintainability.

My question:

1. Is it really best practice to have a services.AddScoped for each and every lookup table in the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`?
2. It is a generic repository so isn't there be a way to write those 100 copy and paste lines in one line?
3. If not then what is the best practice way to do this using my code?

Comment: You use constructor of `Lookup1Controller` with `IGenericRepository<Lookup1>` *as parameter*: `public Lookup1Controller(IGenericRepository<Lookup1> repository)`. Thus you expect that *MVC calls* the controller constructor `Lookup1Controller` with the corresponding parameter. Who should make `new GenericRepository<Lookup1>>()`? Should one do this once or on every call of `Index` action? Thus you have choice between `services.AddTransient`, `services.AddScoped`, `services.AddSingleton` and `services.AddInstance`.

Comment: It's a basic CRUD system. So there is Create. Update, Delete methods I omitted. Using AddScoped seems to be the standard way to do it See:http://wildermuth.com/2015/3/17/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_3_-_EF7. If there is a better way please share.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Just use the non-generic registration overloads (the ones where you need to pass the 2 `Type` objects.) Then provide the [open generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net) of both your interface and the implementation:

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

In your controller, add a dependency for a repository of a specific type (a closed generic type):

```cs
public HomeController(IGenericRepository<Lookup1> repository)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing the one line of code works. Will wait to see if others give input if it's good practice or not for an ASP.net 5 app or provide alterantives

Comment: The way they are registered is the same as for other DI containers like [Ninject](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10243699/1836935) or [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936(v=pandp.20).aspx#Anchor_0). Let's just see if anybody is aware of any gotchas with the built-in container in ASP .Net 5

Comment: This does not works for me. I got this error: fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0] An unhandled exception has occurred: Unable to resolve service for type 'SqlExpress.Repository.Interfaces.IChatRepository' while attempting to activate 'SqlExpress.Helpers.LessonTagHelper'. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SqlExpress.Repository.Interfaces.IChatRepository' while attempting to activate ' SqlExpress.Helpers.LessonTagHelper'. at ...

Comment: In case anyone else has the same issue, I was pulling my hair out over this error when starting the app: Cannot instantiate implementation type Repo1[T]' for service type IRepo1[T]'.' - This was happening because my Repo implementation was marked as abstract, I was able to fix it by simply removing the abstract declaration.

Comment: @jmdon Thank you! I was about to lose my mind... That's what I get for refactoring before coffee kicks in.

For others who stumble upon this, make sure if you change your abstract to concrete that it has a public constructor, btw. My base repo that got a promotion to concrete generic had a protected ctor, which will also die on injection attempts.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I started to see this because Jetbrains Rider recommended I change my GenericRepository constructor from public to protected which I did without thinking..

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to register all `IGenericRepository<>` implementations in Assembly:

```
services.AddAllGenericTypes(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), new[] {typeof(MyDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly});
```

With extension from:
https://gist.github.com/GetoXs/5caf0d8cfe6faa8a855c3ccef7c5a541