# How to resolve generic interface to generic implementation when using dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have created a generic repository that I want to be used in a service.

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseRepository<TEntity, TEntityKey>
        : IBaseRepository<TEntity, TEntityKey>
        where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity<TEntityKey>, new() { /* some code */ }
```

And the interface:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity, TEntityKey> { /* some code */ }
```

On my service I inject the repository like this:

```
public class TenantsService : AbstractBaseService<TenantEntity, int>
{
    public TenantsService(IBaseRepository<TenantEntity, int> tenantsRepository)
        : base(tenantsRepository) { }
}
```

On my startup, on the *ConfigureServices* method, I have:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseRepository<,>), typeof(AbstractBaseRepository<,>));
```

I added this startup code based on the following two answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33567396

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094684

When I run the application I am getting the following error:

> Cannot instantiate implementation type
>   'Playground.Repositories.Base.AbstractBaseRepository`2[TEntity,TEntityKey]'
>   for service type
>   'Playground.Repositories.Base.IBaseRepository`2[TEntity,TEntityKey]'

Comment: Have you tried AddSingleton in place of AddScoped in startup.cs ?

Comment: You're asking the DI container to instantiate an *`abstract`* class, which, [by definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract), *can't be instantiated*.

Comment: That makes sense. Isn't there a way to specify that we want the interface to resolve to any class that extends a given class? In this case any class that extends the AbstractBaseRepository?

Comment: For extra functionality like that, see [Default service container replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#default-service-container-replacement) in the docs. Another option is to use something like [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor).

Comment: What you're asking for is whether there is an _assembly scanning feature that allows you to auto-register all non-generic implementations of your generic abstraction_. Answer is: no, such feature does not exist out of the box. I agree with @KirkLarkin, Scrutor adds this missing functionality on top of ASP.NET Core's built-in container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseRepository<TenantEntity, int>), typeof(TenantsService));
```

As Kirk Larkin mentioned in the comments, you're telling it to instantiate an `abstract` class for `services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseRepository<,>), typeof(AbstractBaseRepository<,>));` which it can't do.