# .NetCore Create Default FluentValidator for all Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to have .Net Cores' dependency injector use a default validator for all created new Service types.

My startup looks like this:

```
services.AddMvc(config => config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizationPolicy)))
      .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
```

and my Default Validator looks like this:

```
public class DefaultValidator<TEntity> : AbstractValidator<TEntity>
{
}
```

It's really annoying having to register the validator for every new service I create, I would like to use the default one for any unknown registered type.

I know it can be view as semi dangerous but this is for testing purposes and I can have it throw if it's on production so thats not an issue.

How can I register a default Validator with .Net Core's Dependency Injector?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33567396/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi, Thanks that should be perfect I didn't know you could register things generically

Comment: Now I am not totally sure it works with this framework. I never really tested it personally. But I've seen this question asked before and remembered that post. I believe it should work though.

Comment: If you post this as an answer I'll accept it, it may be a small niche of people looking for this, but it may help in the future

Comment: Ok found an article that confirms it https://ardalis.com/registering-open-generics-in-aspnet-core-dependency-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to register using open generics like in this example

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(DefaultValidator<>));
```