# ASP.NET Core, How configure generic services in dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I do have added some services to the startup method on Startup.cs.

This service is a Generic service for a specific Type. Here is my startup code:

```
services.AddTransient<BaseEntityService<Subscription>>();
services.AddTransient<BaseEntityService<Customer>>();
services.AddTransient<BaseEntityService<Asset>>();
services.AddTransient<BaseEntityService<Product>>();
// ...
```

O my Controller I require the service like:

```
public MyAssetController(BaseEntityService<Asset> service){ //...
```

Is there a way to do not repeat the generic service to every class type on the startup? just add a generic type? like this:

```
services.AddTransient<BaseEntityService>(); // Doesn't works..
```

Comment: I would just take the generic type parameter off the class and put it on the methods, then you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(BaseEntityService<>));
```

Something similar was mentioned here: [Generic repository in ASP.NET Core without having a separate AddScoped line per table in Startup.cs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566075/generic-repository-in-asp-net-core-without-having-a-separate-addscoped-line-per)

EDIT: Removed the first parameter as the type was the same.

Comment: Please kindly do not post other SO answer. Instead, please close it as duplicate.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry new here.

Comment: Click on close link at the bottom of the question. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLWm1.png) is the screen shot.

Comment: Sorry but I need 3000 rep for that option.

Comment: There is a difference about what you mentioned and the other question..
The question does mention 'AddScoped' and here you mentioned 'AddTransient' . Is that correct?

Comment: Transient classes are created every time they are requested.
Scoped is once per request.
Singleton is lifetime (but created on their first time being requested)

Info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options