# What is the DI equivalent for NInject DI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, ninject, .net-4.6

I am currently migrating from .net4.6 which uses NInject modules. My target is to use .net6 core and its native DI. While doing so I came across a statement from NInject for which I am wondering if there is an equivalent for the same in .net6 native DI ?

```
this.Kernel.Bind(typeof(ICachePoolProvider<>)).To(typeof(CachePoolProvider<>));
```

Should I register for each type of ICachePoolProvider as shown below?

```
services.AddSingleton<ICachePoolProvider<string>,CachePoolProvider<string>);
services.AddSingleton<ICachePoolProvider<QueueClient>,CachePoolProvider<QueueClient>);
services.AddSingleton<ICachePoolProvider<NamespaceManager>,CachePoolProvider<NamespaceManager>);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used NInject but from your code I expect the method you are searching for is:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ICachePoolProvider<>), typeof(CachePoolProvider<>));
```

You can find a good example of an `IGenericRepository` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566075/generic-repository-in-asp-net-core-without-having-a-separate-addscoped-line-per)