# registering classes implementing a generic interface using ninject

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I have this interface:

```
   public interface IObjectFactory<T>
   {
      T NewObject();
   }
```

and I could have multiple classes that implement this interface with a different paramenter like this

```
   public class UserFactory : IObjectFactory<IUser>
   {
      public IUser NewObject() => new User(); 
   }
```

I would like to scan all the assemblies for binding all the classes so I can use without to create a direct binding instruction.
The problem I have is a generic interface and normal samples don't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Already tried but the problem is that I have an interface with generic paramters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243632/how-to-bind-generic-type-interfaces-in-ninject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ninject.extensions.conventions.

```
kernel.Bind(
    c => c.FromThisAssembly()
        .SelectAllClasses()
        .InheritedFrom(typeof(IObjectFactory<>))
        .BindAllInterfaces());
```